# AJAX - "Success" action is not invoked when specifying contentType and dataType

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I run into a little bit of a problem executing `AJAX request.

When specifying `contentType` and `dataType`, `success` section is not executing.
However, when omitting that, it is executing, but is showing the entire content of generated `html` page.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
    data: '{frequency: "' + $('#ddlFrequency option:selected').text() + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#rptDisplay').text(data);
        alert("1");
    },
    failure: function () {
        //                $('#rptDisplay').text("Error");
        alert("2");
    }
});
```

This is `code behind`:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void GeneratePdfs(string frequency)
{
    string test = frequency;
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Write(test);
}
```

This is the fragment of `html` page:

```
<div id="rptDisplay" class="well" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">

</div>
```

I need to display data returned from `Web Method` in my `div` section.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

**contentType** :When sending data to the server.

**dataType:** The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response .

Please find the code:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GeneratePdfs(string frequency)
    {
        string test = "frequency";//Hard Code value
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        return test;
    }

     Design:
      <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent"   ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
      <div id="rptDisplay" class="well" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">

      </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
        data: '{frequency: "' + $('#ddlFrequency option:selected').text() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
       // dataType: "text/Json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data.d!="") {
                $('#rptDisplay').text(data.d);
            }
            alert("1");
        },
        failure: function () {
            //                $('#rptDisplay').text("Error");
            alert("2");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank's. Now it displays the data